# Is there a term for completing graduation and post-graduation degree from the same college?

Tags: graduation, alumni

I have done my graduation from a college in India and I am pursuing my M. Tech from the same college. When I get my degree will I be a "double alumnus" of the institution? Or is the term something else? Please help.

Comment: Still only alumnus, it does not stack.

Comment: A less-PC, colourful term also used is "academic incest."